# div auto expand to the height of its container

Tags: html, css

How can I make a div auto expand to the height of its container?

Here is an example of what the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/weQeh/

I have tried using the CSS atributes `height: auto` and `height: 100%` and this has not worked.

This is a problem I have come across a lot and I have never found and answer to it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/weQeh/7/ is this what u want?

Comment: @Simon, you should take a look to your jsfiddle. It seems that you pasted twice a pice of code leaving some id's duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css `tables` to make the desired layout. Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/weQeh/11/

Answer (score 0):

Add Below CSS to inner div whose height you want to be same as it's parent.

```
position : absolute; top : 0; bottom :0;
```

**left :0;** if you want it to be on Left side of container

**OR**

**right :0;** if you want it to be on Right side of container.

`position : relative;` to parent div.